# How to check if a list contains a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I test if the string "Orange" without quotes, exists in a list such as the one below, using javascript?

```
var suggestionList = ["Apple", "Orange", "Kiwi"];
```

Comment: what do you mean by without quotes?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is the default to use in such cases.

```
if( suggestionList.indexOf("Orange") > -1 ) {
    console.log("success");
}
```

.indexOf() returns the position in the array (or string) of the found element. When no elements are found it returns `-1`.

Things to consider:

- It *will* return 0 if the first object matches, so you **cannot** just cast to boolean.
- Since es2016 you can use `suggestionList.includes('Kiwi');` which will return a boolean directly. (Does not work in internet explorer, but works in IEdge)
- includes polyfill for older browsers: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

Comment: "indexOf()" seems to be the answer, thank you, but it really seems like an unintuitive name for "find within", do you know why it's called indexOf?

Comment: Ah, as I just edited in, it's specific use is to find exactly where (the index) the element is in the array, so on the contrary I find the naming quite fitting. As in: The *index of* `orange` in your array is 1.